# StAX get current event after calling getElementText()

Tags: java, xml, stax

Per [stax specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#getElementText%28%29), the `getElementText()` returns the text data and places the current event as the `END_ELEMENT`.

How do I get access to this `END_ELEMENT`, as the `XMLEventReader` does not have any method to access the current event? `peek()` and `next()` methods provide next event in the XML.

Comment: why do you need the end element, it doesn't contain any thing all that useful?

Comment: my code required to split the xml stream into different files. I was able to overcome using the answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Better off interpreting the events

```
            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();

                // check the element
                if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart() == ("MyTag")) {

                    // We read the attributes from this tag

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Iterator<Attribute> attributes = (Iterator<Attribute>) startElement
                            .getAttributes();
                    while (attributes.hasNext()) {
                        Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
                        if (attribute.getName().toString().equals("myattribute")) {
                            System.out.println("Attribute Value: " + attribute.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (event.isEndElement()) {
                EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart() == ("MyTag")) { 
                    // do Something 
                    }
                }
            } // end while
```